# Google Vision visual search in local database

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vuejs2, nativescript

i want to create a visual search for my app and my Redis database.
Redis is caching products from an external api, which contains products like Nike sneakers, hoodies, hats and so on.

So now i want to search with Google Vision in this database, is that possible?

Comment: Please explain how exactly you are trying to use Google Vision and what issues you are facing.

Comment: @Manoj thx for your reply. i am creating an app, where i can scan objects with my mobile, like a Nike sneaker. Also i have a local Redis database, where i store products from an API. 
Now i want to connect to Redis and i want to check, if this scaned Nike sneaker is in my Redis, if yes, wonderful, if not show me similar products.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible by analysing what's in your image, then search with that on Redis. You will have to create an ML module and feed enough information.

Comment: Thx @Manoj :-) That was also in my mind. Have a nice day.